# sortexpression gridview order desc doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, gridview

hi have a gridview with sortexpression setted in columns.
If i click on column title the table is ordered by asc, if  i click another time on title column the table doesn't change.

I want that on second click the table is ordered by desc.

How can i do it?

thanks

Comment: Could you list some of your GridView markup? Are you setting a datasource?